# UIWebView supporting closing and opening of pages

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm building an application that has a very simple UIWebview page. The page loads a URL of a mobile site that I have that is already built. The mobile site has the ability to log in using Facebook for the users to use. When you bring up the mobile URL in safari at hit "log-in with Facebook" safari opens up a new page which allows them to log it. Once the user logs in safari closes that page, and takes the user back to the mobile website where they are now logged in using Facebook. Now that's fine and everything, but when I integrated a UIWebView into the app I'm building there is a problem. The UIWebView takes me to the mobile site, and it will even allow me to click "log-in with Facebook", AND it takes me to the page where I can log in with Facebook... BUT, once I try and log in, the UIWebview DOESN'T take me back to the main mobile page. The only thing that happens is that the page goes white. I believe it has to do with the fact that the UIWebView does not know how to close that page and go back to the main page. Is there anyway that I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, which describes how to implement a similar requirement to use OAUTH authentication with LinkedIn.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-worklight-linkedin/

The net is that can you use the Cordova along with the InAppBrowser plugin to give you the opportunity to intercept the redirect request coming back from Facebook following authentication.  The article above describes doing this with IBM Worklight, but you can ignore that part... :)